# Sources for visual explanations?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, visualization, diagrams

Does anyone has sources for visual explanations of algorithms (or maths) that is even more expressive, more intuitive, maybe aesthetically appealing ? Or, animations of algorithms?

Comment: I agree with NXC: http://www.google.com/search?q=Algorithm+Animations will give you a lot of results relevant to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start the discussion.

I like the **[database / transaction deadlock](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Deadlocks4Dummy.aspx)** illustrated to a non-technical person.

You have also a lot of good animations on the **[Relevant Algorithm Animations/Visualizations](http://www.ansatt.hig.no/frodeh/algmet/animate.html)** page

Answer (score 2):

Here's one for [sorting algorithms](http://vision.bc.edu/~dmartin/teaching/sorting/anim-html/all.html). It gives some nice animations to see how each type works their way through the process.

Answer (score 2):

[Animal](http://www.algoanim.info/Animal2/) is a cross-platform animation tool for algorithm animation.

Animation scripts for a lot of common algorithms and data structures are available in the website's [animation repository](http://www.algoanim.info/Animal2/?q=node/268).

Comment: Animal was used to teach us many different kinds of algorithms on data structures in my first CS class in college. It's really pretty neat.

A few years back I played around with AnimalScript, and I remember it being rather straightforward to create new animations.

Comment: It is still being used in academia and they continue to improve it and the tools around it (mainly for creating new animation scripts). They just don't seem to find the time to update the website often enough, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for [insert name of algorithm] and 'applet'.  Many academics and other such people have made java applets to demonstrate algorithms working.  You can probably find an example for just about any published algorithm.